# Extract audio from live video stream

Tags: video-streaming, digital-ocean, audio-streaming, rtmp

Apologies if this has been asked before... I'm trying to figure out how to extract the audio from a live stream. Using digital ocean's ant media server as a rtmp source for the video. Trying to build a page on a website that would feel like the hallway between two rooms with live performances happening - where you can hear the audio from both muddled together. I've considered just adding the two video streams and hiding the video, but I'm afraid it would be too much of an unnecessary burden on the server.

Does anyone know of a way to grab just the audio from a stream? And maybe even lower the volume and cut off the high end?

Thanks!

Jill

Comment: `ffmpeg -i <your stream URL> -vn -acodec copy <output URL>`  As for volume and cutoff filter, I would do this client-side with the Web Audio API, so that you can make adjustments.

Comment: Hey @Brad, this is very interesting - I assume this is for the command line. Do you mind elaborating? In terms of doing the audio client-side, yes - there definitely should be controls available, but what about setting up defaults server side?

Comment: Yeah, FFmpeg is a tool you can run on the command line which in the example I mentioned in the comment would take your stream in, drop the video portion, keep the audio part as-is without re-encoding (that's what `-acodec copy` is for), and then output it somewhere for streaming.  You'll have to install it.  Here's the documentation, but honestly it's probably best to download a copy and find a tutorial and experiment:  https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html  Once you have it working manually, you can figure out how you want to call FFmpeg server-side.  (continued in next comment...)

Comment: (... continued from previous comment)  What I usually do is execute FFmpeg as a child process to a Node.js script.  But, you don't have to use Node.js.  You could use whatever you wanted.  (I didn't write up an answer for you because I don't know what you're using server-side.)  As for the filtering, I definitely would not do any filtering server-side.  You won't be able to change it client-side then, if the audio is already processed.  Keep the signal dry up until the Web Audio API on the client.  From there, check out the BiquadFilterNode.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BiquadFilterNode

Comment: This is incredibly helpful - would've never found this. Thank you so much!